# dvnm not a recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: asp.net-core

when you try to run "dnvm list" or any of "dnvm" commands in the command promt i get the error

"dvnm not a recognized as an internal or external  command,operable program or batch file"

I have already installed visual studio 2015 on my windows7 pc.

Comment: Use PowerShell, that works as dnvm.exe is added to its path.

Comment: did you install the latest beta7 tooling? I "think" that would install the latest dnvm and setup the needed environment variables https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Install Powershell 4.0
   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx
2. Run the below command in ***command prompt***

> @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "&{$Branch='dev';$wc=New-Object System.Net.WebClient;$wc.Proxy=[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy;$wc.Proxy.Credentials=[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;Invoke-Expression ($wc.DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}"

or the below command in ***powershell***

> &{$Branch='dev';$wc=New-Object
>   System.Net.WebClient;$wc.Proxy=[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy;$wc.Proxy.Credentials=[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;Invoke-Expression
>   ($wc.DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}

ref :  [asp.net /home github site Upgrading DNVM or running without Visual Studio](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/2e8e5e92a10fd16dda7950728ec54539f81d0792#upgrading-dnvm-or-running-without-visual-studio)

3. run command in command prompt

> dnvm list

The command promt may ask you that you dint have any and install the latest 
say yes and it installs successfully.

Sample output is shown below

> C:\Windows\system32>dnvm list
>
> Getting started It looks like you don't have any runtimes installed.
>   Do you want us to install a DNX to get you started?
>   [Y] Yes  [N] No
>
> [?] Help (default is "Y"): **y**
>
> Determining latest version Downloading
>   dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7 from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
>   Installing to C:\Users\YourAdminUserName.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7
>   Adding C:\Users\YourAdminUserName.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7\bin to
>   process PA
>   .....and so on

That it you are ready to roll..

Comment: When I execute 
&{$Branch='dev';$wc=New-Object System.Net.WebClient;$wc.Proxy=[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy;$wc.Proxy.Credentials=[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;Invoke-Expression ($wc.DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}

Comment: I install this many times but today I run step 2 on my server then run step 3 but get dvnm not a recognized ....so strange

Comment: I find the problem. go to .dnx\bin there is dnvm. maybe it didn't add it to enviroment variable

Comment: You will need to close and re-open your cmd window after step 2. The updated path will not find "dnvm" until this is done.