# .NET Core on Raspbian/ARM?

Tags: .net, raspberry-pi, raspbian, iot, .net-core

We know .NET Core supports Linux x64 and x86, MacOS X, Windows... but is it ready to use in Linux for Raspberry Pi? (Raspbian, for example).

Comment: I'm not sure that they support `ARM` yet, but you can always install mono that should be in Raspbian repository

Comment: Some relevant discussion here: http://forums.dotnetfoundation.org/t/can-we-use-net-core-on-arm-processors/1291

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run .NET Core on Raspberry PI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907857/is-it-possible-to-run-net-core-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Found a relavant thread, http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41762/visual-studio-code-net-core-arm-support

Comment: Considering that the core CLR unit test run for a month now.... I bet on Build 2017 conference ☺

Comment: [More recent discussion here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9168).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core 2.1 supports Raspberry Pi.

Here is how to install .NET Core 2.1 on Raspberry Pi:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y update
$ sudo apt-get -y install libunwind8 gettext
$ wget https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.300/dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-linux-arm.tar.gz
$ wget https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/aspnetcore/Runtime/2.1.0/aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.0-linux-arm.tar.gz
$ sudo mkdir /opt/dotnet
$ sudo tar -xvf dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-linux-arm.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet/
$ sudo tar -xvf aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.0-linux-arm.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet/
$ sudo ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin
$ dotnet --info
```

Comment: Can we compile also on RaspberryPi now?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin It seems so! dotnet new console ;D

Comment: @SuperJMN have you tried it? (as I see you changed the accepted answer :D)

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Yes, I tried and works perfectly :) it builds, too!

Comment: @SuperJMN perfect, that will make the life much easier. Thank you!

Comment: Why is this needed? => https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/aspnetcore/Runtime/2.1.0/aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.0-linux-arm.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

According to discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/447) **sample solution is working on Raspbian**. Official instructions are [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md).

Personally I'm using Ubuntu Server Standard as in [this guide](https://dotnetcorechris.github.io/dotnetcoreonraspberrypi.html) but I suppose that is not linux for raspberry as mentioned in your question.

Comment: I can confirm that it runs on an RPi 3 rocking Ubuntu 16.04. Unfortunately not with enough performance to handle my ASP.NET Core app...but it does run.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial describes (in German) how to up [.NET Core on Linux (Raspberry Pi)](https://www.dotnet.xyz/tutorials/net-core-unter-linux-raspberry-pi/). This is an automated [English translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dotnet.xyz%2Ftutorials%2Fnet-core-unter-linux-raspberry-pi%2F&edit-text=).

Comment: About halfway down the translation abruptly stops and it continues only in German.

Comment: Fortunately enough, using the Edge browser and its Translator Extension, the translation is all the way in English.

Comment: I successfully followed the steps until I reached the "dnvm upgrade -u" command. It says it "Cannot find the command". Anyone?

Comment: Maybe it is not installed. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130092/dvnm-not-a-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat

Comment: @DmitryPavlov Sure, but how do I install it in Raspbian for the RPi3?

Comment: It seems to be not possible for RPi3 yet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013926/net-core-installation-on-windows-10-iot-raspberry-pi3-arm Or maybe I am wrong and it is possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560892/is-net-core-ready-to-run-on-raspberry-pi-3 Feel free to look the related threads and follow the instructions. Or maybe even try to be a pioneer and be the first who made something working.