# .net core installation on Windows 10 iot (Raspberry PI3 - ARM)

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-10-iot-core, coreclr, dnvm

I test .net core on different OSs and I'd like to know if it's possible to install dotnet/cli (.net Core) on Windows 10 iot over my Raspberry PI3. My objective would be ro run simple GPIO tests.

What I do so far :

- I went on the [.NET core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) site and do not find anything about Windows 10 iot target.
- I found a nice blog post titled [How to run .NET Core Application on Pi2 - Win10 IoT Core?](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2015/09/22/how-to-run-net-core-application-on-pi2-win10-iot-core.aspx) but it use [DNVM](https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm) which seems to be obsolete, and I don't read anything about Windows 10 iot target in the sites that are supposed to replace it.

Do I miss something ? is it too early to do that ?

PS : I push an [issue in dotnet/cli](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4400) issues in GitHub.

**2017-04-19** : The process is now in progress have a look to [.NET Core on Raspberry Pi](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md)

Comment: `but it use DNVM which seems to be obsolete` -> And you read the readme? "DNX and DNVM have been replaced by the new .NET CLI. See..."

Comment: The .NET CLI (dotnet) is what I'am looking for. I don't if it exists an ARM version of it, and how it can be installad on my RPI3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arm32 builds are available as community supported builds for .NET Core 2.0. There is no SDK that runs on ARM32 but you can publish an application that will run on a Raspberry Pi. look to [.NET Core on Raspberry Pi](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md).

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, [it's not in yet](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/243).

During the development of .net core, various people have managed to hack bits together to get it running on all sorts of stuff. But Win10 IoT and other ARM devices, have never got to the "officially supported" level.

Comment: Are you aware of a team that try to work on it, I can do some QA.

Comment: Afraid not, it was on the roadmap at one point, but it has since been removed, so I don't think it's being actively worked on at this time. Looking through the various repos on github, people are still saying it's coming, there is just no firm dates as to when they will start working on it.

Answer (score 0):

.net Core is available on ARM: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/articles/core/
An UWP app for example runs on .net Core. 
Here is a link to the cli doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/

Comment: Yes the the process is in progress : https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md